# Update Query Single Column Multiple Rows But Not All

Tags: database, rows

I'm using the SQL query box in phpMyAdmin (MyISAM).  Below works fine unless I try updating more than one row at a time.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = 'Air'
WHERE row_name = 's003';

If I try adding say 'tr003, s005';  -- that won't work.  I get message "0 rows affected".  I have searched but couldn't find help for this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `IN` clause for this:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET column_name = 'Air' 
WHERE row_name in ('s003', 'tr003', 's005');
```

Comment: Thank you, RedFilter - thought I had tried that but didn't work at the time.  I copied yours exactly and it worked (must have left something out before.  I also just tried

Comment: Well, forget what I was trying to add to my comment...I have the most wicked time trying to post my comments in acceptable format - it's quite intimidating.  Thank goodness I find answers to most of my questions by trolling.  I really appreciate this forum.